# Shell Script "read" functions - not a valid identifier

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I'm making a shell script to install my program ImagicalMine.

I'm trying to implement a language function for the installation script but I run into errors.

I use a "message" function to call another shell script which includes all the messages stored into variables, then use `echo` to output the variable to output the message. I'm running into errors near the end of the script, where at line 127 it says:

> "read '(e.g.': not a valid identifier".

I've been trying to resolve this issue for days. The shell script is [here](https://github.com/ImagicalMine/php-build-scripts/blob/master/install1.sh), and the language file is [here](https://github.com/ImagicalMine/php-build-scripts/blob/master/language/en.sh) - I didn't post it here because it may be too long. Any ideas?

Comment: welcome to SO. Could we please see some code and maybe the errors too? This would greatly help us in helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the variables containing spaces and similar characters, e.g.:

```
read -e -p "$no_selection" t
```